# How to reverse all words in a string in-place also reverse those words' place in the string, while keep punctuations in their old place

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, reverse

In case the title is not clear, here is an example:
The input:

```
'hello  howis.going'
```

Expected output:

```
'ginog  siwoh.olleh'.
```

Is it possible to program it with regular expression?

Below is my code,

```
function fn(str) {
  return str.replace(/[^\s.]+/g, function(m) {
    return m.split('').reverse().join('');
  });
 }

 var res = fn('hello  howis.going')
 console.log('result = ', res);
```

Here is my output now:

```
olleh  siwoh.gniog
```

Comment: You might use a regular expression to find words and the characters between them, but you'll need more logic to reverse and replace them so as to keep punctuation, etc. in the same place in the sentence.

Comment: so, what would you expect the result of applying this function to "hello. my question is unclear" ... "raelc.nu si noitseuq ym olleh" ?

Comment: @RobG Yes, that's why I post it here. I want to see is there are any tricks that I forget...

Comment: @JaromandaX emm this is a good question, will it be easier that why?

Comment: Then `/[a-z]+|[^a-z]+/ig` will match sequences of a-z and not a-z to create an array. Now you can swap words and reverse them and join the array back together with the punctuation in the original position.

Comment: For the string `a!bb.ccc.dddd`, what is the expected output? My code returns `d!dd.dcc.cbba` - keeping punctuation in its original place. Titus's code returns `dddd!ccc.bb.a` - keeping punctuation between the words. Can you add some more example, with words in different lengths?

Comment: This seems the topic about how to output captured characters reversely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you could do is to create an array of all the words in the string, reverse the array and then start replacing each word in the string with the words in the reversed array.

Here is an example:

```js
function process(s){
  let arr = s.replace(/\W+$/, "").split(/\W+/).reverse();
  let index = 0;
  return s.replace(/\w+/g, function(){
    return arr[index++].split("").reverse().join("");
  });
}

console.log(process("hello  howis.going"));
```

EDIT: Added `.replace(/\W+$/, "")` to prevent empty string elements at the end of the array for cases when the string contains non-word character(s) at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `match` to create an array of letters you want to move, and then [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) and [`pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) from that array:

```js
function fn(str){
  var moved = /\w/g; // use moved = /[\w ]/g to also move spaces.
  var letters = str.match(moved, '');
  var altered = str.replace(moved, function(){return letters.pop();});
  return altered;
}
    
console.log(fn('hello  howis.going'));
console.log(fn('Also in ... different lengths!'));
console.log(fn('a.bb.ccc.dddd'));
```

If you also want to move spaces, you can change the first line in the function to `/[\w ]/g`:

```js
function fn(str){
    var moved =  /[\w ]/g;
    var letters = str.match(moved, '');
    var altered = str.replace(moved, function(){return letters.pop();});
    return altered;
}

console.log(fn('hello  howis.going'));
console.log(fn('Also in ... different lengths!'));
console.log(fn('a.bb.ccc.dddd'));
```